# Laravel Middleware Performing Action Before Form Submission

Tags: php, laravel

I am just creating a random app to check if the user is eligible for voting or not. I am using middleware to check if age is less than 18 then redirect to /age/validate. But the problem is the middleware is performing action before form submission. Please help.

Form::

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'AgeController@store', 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
    {!! Form::number('age', null) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Check') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Middleware::

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->age <= 18){
        return redirect()->route('noteligble');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/age/validate', function(){
    echo 'You are not eligible to vote';
})->name('noteligble');

Route::resource('checkage', 'AgeController')->middleware('agechecker');
```

Please Help me how i can make middleware work only after form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A middleware is executed *before* every request. You're assigning the middleware to the whole resource and therefore to the route which displays the form.

---

### The solution

Assign the middleware only to the store method in the controller. Remove the `->middleware('agechecker')` method call from your routes file and add assign that in your controller constructor like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('agechecker')
         ->only(['store']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro! Understood all the things.